# Unable to receive a JSON response after a POST request

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express, response

Context:
I want to collect information from the users and compare them with the data in the database. After comparing, I want all the matches to be send back to the frontend.

I am able to receive the request body and compare the data in the backend (express, MySQL). However, I am unable to send back the response to the frontend (vue).

The following is my code:

Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/`
  })
}
```

PreferenceService.js

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  async preference (credentials) {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    try {
      const response = await Api().post('preference', credentials, {
        timeout: 5000,
        headers: headers
      })

      console.log(response.data)
      return response.data

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

Preference.vue

```
<script>
  import PreferenceService from '../services/PreferenceService'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        gender: '',
        yearsOfExp: '',
        typesOfTraining: '',
        gymLocation: '',
        error: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async preference () {
        try {
          const response = await PreferenceService.preference({
            gender: this.gender,
            yearsOfExp: this.yearsOfExp,
            typesOfTraining: this.typesOfTraining,
            gymLocation: this.gymLocation
          })

          console.log(response)
          
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') {
            console.log('Request timed out')
          } else {
            console.log(error.message)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

PreferenceController.js

```
const {User} = require('../models')
module.exports = {
    async preference (req, res, next) {
        try {
            const { gender, yearsOfExp, typesOfTraining, gymLocation } = req.body
            const users = await User.findAll({
                where: {
                    gender: gender,
                    yearsOfExp: yearsOfExp,
                    typesOfTraining: typesOfTraining,
                    gymLocation: gymLocation
                }
            })

            if (!users) {
                console.log('no user')
                return res.status(403).send ({
                    error: "no user"
                })
            }

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(users))

        } catch (err) {
            console.log('not in ' + err)
            res.status(400).send({
                error: 'item not received'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The network status shown to me in Chrome is:

[image: network status img]

The network status shown to me in Firefox is:

[image: network status img]

The error shown on Firefox console is:

> Object { stack: "AxiosError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:23:19\nhandleAbort@webpack-
> internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:161:14\nEventHandlerNonNull*dispatchXhrRequest@webpack-
> .
> .
> .
> message: "Request aborted", name: "AxiosError", code: "ECONNABORTED", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }

I tried to increase the timeout timing but it does not work either.

I am expected to see the response (list of matched users) in the console but currently it is not showing anything.

Also, I have tried to send back a basic response such as `res.status(200).send('working')` and this is working.

Comment: You are running here into a Cross origin problem, you can't just load a page from localhost:8080 and do your api requests to localhost:8081 as this is like a different server. You have to at least include a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on your api request with value http://localhost:8080/* by an additonal res.setHeader call.

Comment: hi! I am new to this cross origin issue. I have tried adding the additional res.setHeader call but I still cannot get the response, is there anything else I am missing out?

Comment: Try putting some console.log(...) At the top of the controller so that you can check if request is properly getting handled or not. Post the results in comment, I will be happy to help you out.

Comment: in try {} i have added the following console log
console.log('in')

const { gender, yearsOfExp, typesOfTraining, gymLocation } = req.body
console.log(gender)
console.log(yearsOfExp)
console.log(typesOfTraining)
console.log(gymLocation)
const users = await User.findAll({
where: {
gender: gender,
yearsOfExp: yearsOfExp,
typesOfTraining: typesOfTraining,
gymLocation: gymLocation}})

console.log(users)

res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080/')
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(users))

Comment: the results:

in
Male
Less than one year
Calisthenics
ActiveSG
[
  User {
    dataValues: {
      id: 25,
      name: 'loks',
      email: 'loklok@gmail.com',
      password: '$2a$08$CpieXnEjltX9CuNtDryUgODAYdOjImu.xlqcTufOKlLR6mQD.8Ys2',
      age: 21,
      gender: 'Male',
      gymFreq: 'Two times a week',
      yearsOfExp: 'Less than one year',
      typesOfTraining: 'Calisthenics',
      gymLocation: 'ActiveSG'
    },
    ... //more matched users
]

Comment: sorry for the ugly formatting, basically i can get the all the data in the backend from the form in the frontend.
After i findAll users in the database, it gives me back an array of user json object and i want to send this data back to the frontend to display on the page using res but i am unable to do so

Comment: the response can be received on postman but not on the frontend